# How can I validate the size of a file in the Laravel driver?

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5.5

I have a form in which I validate with javascript that the size of the file does not exceed 2MB, but I also want to do this validation on the server.

Does laravel have any function to validate with "Validation" that does not exceed a specific size? Any other way would also be good for me.

I'm working with Laravel 5.5.

Comment: Yes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation, the `size` rule.

Comment: With size it does not work because it would have to be that size.

Comment: Sorry, use `max` instead.

Comment: No problem, thanks for responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'file' => 'file|max:2024'
    ]);

    // The form post is valid...
}
```

[min](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-min)

```
'file' => 'file|min:2024'
```

[max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-max)

```
'file' => 'file|max:2024'
```

Comment: Perfect, that is the way, I was trying with the size, but this way it did not work for me, but with maximum or minimum it works correctly. Thank you.